# Can nested HTML list items be forced to be aligned to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can nested HTML list items be forced to be aligned to the left? for eg:

- Bat
- Cat
- Rat

  - one
  - two
  - three
- Mat

```
<ul>
    <li>Bat</li>
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>Rat<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul></li>
    <li>Mat</li>
</ul>
```

Should look like(without removing nested list) :

- Bat
- Cat
- Rat

  one

  two

  three
- Mat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

By setting the `margin` and `padding` to zero of the nested `ul` elements, all the elements will be moved to the left side.

Some old browsers uses `padding` to indent the list elements. So, set the `padding` also to zero, for all the browsers.

Set the `list-style-type: disc;` to set the style of all the elements same.

```css
ul ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Bat</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Rat
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Mat</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @misterManSam Some old browsers use `margin` and some uses `padding` to elements

Comment: Downvoter, Can something be improved? Please add comment here

Comment: @Tushar - You're right, IE11 is the first IE version that uses padding for list items by default. IE10 and below use margin. The more you know :)

Answer (score 0):

[check here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SYQxHdUpFXtDz9xYnhHu?p=preview)

Use margin-left:-40px; and using css you can make thi`enter code here`s more improved one